# On how to do a division in a different base.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I was wondering if there was a quick way to compute multiplication and division in a base different from base $10$.

Say for example we are in base $12$ then $3*16=40$ the way I do this is by noticing that in base $10$ we have that $3*16=48$ and that $48= 4*12$ so in base twelve $4*16 = 48 - 4*2 = 40$ where $2$ is given by $12-10$.

Is this the fastest approach?

Also, in the same way, I can notice that when $12*4<ab<12*6$ (where $a,b$ belong to the number sistem in base 12) the last digit of the number in base $12$ will be the same as that in base $10$.

What about division? in particular is there a quick way to figure out the last digit of the result of a division by two numbers?

Comment: `quick way to compute multiplication and division` What do you mean by that? Arithmetic operations work on numbers, not on *representations* of numbers, such as those using a base. Six divided by two is three, and is always three, regardless of whether you write it as $\,1010 / 10 = 11\,$ in base $2$, or $\,6/3=2\,$ in any base $\ge 7$, or $VI \,/\, II \,=\, III$ in roman numerals.

Comment: Um.  $3_{12}*16_{12} = 3_{10}*18_{10}= 54_{10}=46_{12}$.

Comment: @dxiv.  $16_{12} = (10_{12}+ 6_{12}$ so the $3*10 + 3*6 = 3*10 +10 + 6 = 46$.

Comment: @fleablood Right, of course. Too late to edit the comment now, and no point to repost since your answer, so I'll just remove it.

Comment: There's *nothing* innate about base 10.  So however you do math in base 10 you do it in base whatever THE EXACT SAME WAY.  The only trouble is you will have to relearn portions of the times and addition tables.  But there are logical shortcuts.

Comment: @dxiv  I kind of like your systematic approach.  My answer is a lot more informal.  Although I'm trying to impress that math is math no matter what base.

Comment: https://youtu.be/UIKGV2cTgqA

Comment: @fleablood It's not entirely clear from the context what kind of answer the question expects. Between my first comment and your `nothing innate about base 10` maybe the OP will clarify whether it's about hand calculation techniques, or computational, or something else entirely.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your answer, you are certainly correct. The question is ambiguous. I was looking for short-cuts on calculation techniques, should I edit somehow?

Comment: @Monolite See also [this](http://core.ecu.edu/csci/wirthj/Basen/bnArith-c.html#BASEN_ADD), [that](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/SysTable.shtml) and [that](http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.bases.html) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faster approach is digit by digit.  Just you would in base $10$.

$3*16$.  You multiply the the $3*6$.  As six is half of 12 (just like 5 is half of ten) $3*6 = 12 + 6 = 16$.  We write the $6$ down and carry the one.  $3*1 = 3$ and we add the one we carried.  So we get $3*16 = 46$.

Notice: $3_{10}*16_{10}=48_{10} = 40_{12} \ne 3_{12}*16_{12} = 46_{12}=54_{10}=3_{10}*18_{10}$.

Keep in mind $16_{12} = 18_{10}$.